# How to model derived types (polymorphism?) in DDD

Tags: design-patterns, domain-driven-design

I have `Orders` which are raised against `Contracts`, which can be set up as either a fixed price contract or as per price per contracts.

During `Contract` setup, allowed `Products` are assinged as `ContractProducts`. For fixed price contracts, `ContractProduct` is set at the `Contract` level, while for price per product `Contracts`, it is set at the `ContractProduct` level.

How would you go about modelling this? A Fixed Price `Contract` will need to hold the fixed price agreed, and a `ContractProduct` would need to hold the price agreed for a per product contract.

Would you have a base `Contract` and `ContractProduct` classes, with derived types to hold the extra pricing information? Something like this

```
public abstract class Order {
 
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Contact Contact { get; set; }

    private List<ContractProduct> {get; set;}

    public void AddProduct(ContractProduct contractProduct){
       .....
    }

    public abstract void CalculateInvoice();
}
```

```
public class FixedPriceOrder : Order {
    
   public decimal Price { get; set; }

    public override void CalculateInvoice(){
        .... logic
    }
}
```

```
public class PerProductPriceOrder : Order {

    public override void CalculateInvoice(){
        .... logic
    }

}
```

```
public abstract class ContractProduct {

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Product Product { get; set; }
 
}
```

```
public class FixedPriceContractProduct : ContractProduct {

}
```

```
public class FixedPriceContractProduct : ContractProduct {

    public decimal Price { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: "but each order is a 'type' which dictates how the invoice is calculated" - so, are you saying that you have a number of different 'order types' which all contribute to the final sum in a certain way that depends on the 'order type'? If so, that does sound like something that could make use of polymorphism: express the calculation in a high-level way, leave details to each specific order. Your idea to "have a base Order and Product classes" indicates that there's potentially some logic split between the two, and there's not enough information given for us to decide if that's good or bad

Comment: I think it would help if you described the (business) problem in more detail

Comment: @filip-milovanović I have expanded the question

Answer (score 5):

I would not use polymorphism of Order to achieve this. I would also argue that DDD doesn't lend itself to this style of OOP.

Instead, I would opt for a Anaemic Domain Model with, a data type for Order, Invoice etc

```
Order
{
    string Id
    string[] ItemIdList
    string OrderType 
}

Invoice
{
    string Id
    string OrderId
    string Price
}
```

And only use OOP/Polymorphism for the InvoiceCalculator

```
InvoiceCalculator_PerItem : IInvoiceCalculator
{
    Invoice CreateInvoice(Order o)
    {
       //load per item contract details to work out price
    }
}

InvoiceCalculator_FixedPrice : IInvoiceCalculator
{
    Invoice CreateInvoice(Order o)
    {
        //load contract for the customer to work out the price
    }
}
```

The Business can now invent a million different types of order and I will never have the discussion with them about whether a XmasSpecialOrder is a type of AnniversaryGiftOrder or a subset of HolidaySaleOrder and how that affects the processing thereof.

If the calculator needs extra information then I would hold that separately from the Order

```
PerItemContract
{
   string
   decimal Discount
}

ProductPrice
{
   string PerItemContractId
   string ProductId
   decimal Price
}

FixedPriceContract
{
   whatever
}
```

etc

Comment: Thanks @Ewan - I have expanded my question a little to make it a little clearer what I'm asking

Comment: the same, just changed the names around. In my experience its a mistake to use inheritance for these kind of "i can make anything I like up" business rules. Keep the data and methods separate